# Is it possible for Earth to have evolved quicker than it did in terms of socialness and technology?

Tags: earth-like

As a writer, I've created a world where the year 1786 is equivalent to 2019 but is a little more advanced in a few ways. Scientifically, would it be possible for Earth to have evolved socially and technologically quicker than it did in real life for human life?

Comment: You mean like...if Rome didn't collapse? Or if a lot of things that happened by chance happened sooner? Sure, why not.

Comment: @DKNguyen no just in general. But if Rome is crucial, then yes.

Comment: Scientifically, an asteroid could have wiped out the dinosaurs 30 million years earlier paving the way for large mammals 30 million years earler, etc. This question is really broad and vague. I think you need to narrow down things a bit more. 233 years is a blink of an eye depending on when you choose to "start" your clock.

Comment: I had a similar idea that I never really got around to writing, but the basic idea was a modest group of people got plucked off of Earth circa 400 AD and managed to develop sci-fi level tech by "today" (circa 2000 AD). It doesn't seem implausible that if the loss of the Library of Alexandra and the Dark Ages hadn't happened, we might be much further along. That said, as noted, you need to be more specific. There are tons of stories with advanced aliens. At what point do you want things to go differently?

Comment: @Matthew Literally from the beginning of humankind. Like they knew how to write from the moment they started existing?

Comment: @ShayleeSpeare In that case everything could be earlier by 200,000 years if everything happened just right or whatever kickstarted things happened earlier without changing the sequence of events afterwards, ignoring stuff like migrations to distribute the population that have to take time with the means available. I think 233 years is completely plausible.

Comment: @DKNguyen WOW. That's amazing

Comment: the Library of Alexandra was attached to a temple of the Muses, and particularly noted for its poetry, not its science.

Comment: The only difference between 2020 and 1786 is an arbitrary and irrelevant calendar reference.The only viable answer is "yes" and it's most easily achieved by shaving a trivial and equally irrelevant 250 years off of the 100,000 year period before the birth of Christ. Of course, what you'd end up with is 2020 with a line through it and the year 1786 written next to it, but otherwise you'd have today.  Without a meaningful fixed starting year, the question is trivial and meaningless. (E.G., starting with 1720, could the world have advanced to 2020's sociotechnical point by 1786?)

Comment: Oh! @DKNguyen already brought up that point. Shay, why don't you either (a) ask relevant to a specific starting point or (b) ask something more like, "What changes at the earliest point of time after 1,000A.D. would permit 2020 sociotech by 1786?" This actually gives you a better reference for picking the "best answer." It's the one that identifies the earliest changes. (Note that we recommend waiting 24 hours before awarding a green check because we have users all over the world and human nature is to stop caring once an answer is selected.)

Comment: I must agree with @JBH. You can easily discard a few centuries from human history. For example, nothing of much consequence happened in the 10th century; discard it. Nothing of much consequence happened in the 9th century BCE. Discard it. You can also easily start everything as much as a few thousand years earlier; agriculture was invented in the 10th millennium before the common era, while history doesn't really begin until the 4th millennium before the common era: you can drastically reduce those 6 millennia between them. Of course, the years which *we* count 1786 won't be counterd 1786...

Comment: @DKNguyen: Or that asteroid could have missed Earth entirely, and some descendent of dinousaurs could have evolved intelligence 50 million years ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The easiest explanation would be the Dark Ages not happening**

It was not a great time to be alive.  The Roman Empire had fallen, the Catholic Church was in control of scientific advancement, plagues were ravaging Europe.  Did I mention invaders?

You've got to make up only 233 years.  The Dark Ages lasted 800 or 900ish years.

Some thoughts...

1. Medieval Europeans never [de-urbanizes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_science_in_the_Middle_Ages), and everyone stays educated.
2. The Catholic Church could have embraced Galileo's model of the solar system.
3. Rome never falls and continues it's research unimpeded from invaders.  Would prevent relearning in Europe in the 1000's

EDIT:

I'm focused on changing European history because in 1786 Europe was in the middle of [Colonialism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colonialism).  To be close to 2019 you'd probably still need this period as several major 20th-century revolutions were against European powers (such as the one lead by Gandhi in India).

Comment: There's also if Islamic golden age had continued and if ancient China broke its isolation earlier.

Comment: Or Pontius Pilate could have said "Hey, that guy's just a nutcase, let him go", and Christianity would never have been anything more than a minor cult, making the western Empire able to fight off the barbarian invasions.  Or Mohammed could have gotten an arrow in the eye during that first caravan robbery, and the Eastern (Byzantine) Empire would have continued.  Or any of a great number of other things.

Comment: This is just that "Christianity=Dark Ages" meme that's been floating around and isn't even supported by real history. If the Roman Empire were still around things would not be advanced socially. Rome was aristocratic as heck and you didn't have much of a voice if you weren't an elite land-owning male. Christianity was important in the de-legitimizing of slavery (even if it took centuries to fully sink in) and the Black Death was key in the rise of the middle class and breaking up the chokehold the aristocracy had on everything.

Comment: Science wouldn't be that much better either, Rome banned research on the human body except for cases like gladiators (e.g., Galen), anatomical and medical science would still be downright backwards compared to places like China. Rome was not known for its science. Not to mention Rome's warped sense of nationalism and liberal rewriting of history to suit propaganda to the point modern historians have trouble trusting Roman records, which doesn't come off as socially advanced. The Dark Ages were bad but it's not like society stopped after Rome.

Comment: It's a myth that learning & technology declined during the European "Dark Ages". More careful study has shown a number of technological development during those centuries, such as the development & adoption of the windmill. We buy into this myth due artifact of historiography: we think literacy & debate was widespread due to emphasis on Plato, Aristotle, Cicero & Pliny when they were a tiny elite minority, while the lives of the majority of the population did not change noticeably between, say, AD 100 & AD 1000 -- except maybe for widespread adoption of Christianity.

Comment: The “Dark Ages” as a concept is no longer used by serious historians. It was a political construction first used by Petrarch to promote the greatness of Latin culture and indirectly his own Italian one.  Later it was used to deingrate Christianity by proponents of the Conflict Thesis and to otherwise promote political change in Europe during the 19th century. It’s simply not a valid historical categorization

Comment: @llywrch You can see the Post-roman decline in living standards across Northern Europe clearly in the archaeological remains. Marble to rough stone. Under floor heating to a firepit in a thatched hut. Disciplined, professional soldiers to tribal warriors.

Comment: @DrMcCleod Your examples are instances of bias selection: yes, there are examples of palaces replaced by less salubrious conditions. But this is no more than proof that one group of elites were replaced with another. And archeological evidence of "tribal warriors" amongst the Roman soldiers has been shown to be little more than a change in fashion. For the vast majority of Europeans, physical culture changed very little between, say, AD 100 & AD 1000: dirt floors, thatched roofs, homespun clothes, widespread illiteracy, & minimal medical care was their unchanged world.

Comment: @llywrch Are there any examples of buildings built to same quality in (say) southern England in the 500 years after the romans left as there were in the ~300 years of their stay?

Comment: There are a number of churches built in that period, some of which are still standing, which are comparable to what the Romans built. But remember, tastes change: so the elite of Anglo-Saxon England may not have wanted stone buildings in the manner the Romans built.

Answer (score 5):

You only want 233 years? Easy enough, but *social development* and *technological development* have different spurs...and sometimes advance in one may lead to regression in the other.

- New technologies and industries tend to develop and prosper in places with access to capital (banking), a trainable workforce (literacy/education), and reasonably fair dispute resolution (rule of law). You don't need all of those, but it sure helps.
- Social development is a little trickier and more complicated in some ways...but weirdly simpler in others. Major changes in social attitudes can happen quickly in response to many stimuli (war, plague, famine) and/or perhaps a bit of leadership. The tough part is preventing regression when the situation changes.

Examples: Try dialing back on corruption and improving leadership in the Byzantine Empire or the Tang Dynasty, so that innovation could flourish. Or bring banking, cross-pollination, and innovation to the Pallava Empire of southern India right between Europe and China, Or change the impact of the Mongolian invasions and bubonic plagues.

Comment: Just have Genghis Khan kill 50% less people out of greed to exploit their labor. Whole extra civilizations would exist. Or have the bubonic plague simply not exist. Possibilities are endless.

Comment: @DWKraus *fewer people, because you can count the number of people

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course - even though the whole Question is way off-topic in Worldbuilding SE.

Assuming you meant not Earth, but civilisation, weren’t the greatest developments in human history iron, steam, penicillin and simple hygiene – in no particular order?

Which of those wasn’t a chance discovery? Most obviously the age of steam is supposed to have come about when someone noticed a kettle lid bouncing up and down. Why could that not have happened 500 or 1,000 years earlier?

Does “in real life for human life” have some special meaning, or is it just confused?

When 1786 is “equivalent to 2019 but a little more advanced in a few ways” should we just guess, or could you be specific?